# Font ligature for text in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, ligature

I am encountering a font ligature issue in a sentence.

The sentence in question is:

---

Verizon is sunseng BlueJeans as the plaorm struggled to gain tracon against rival services in the video conferencing market

---

I have a list of ligatures, and some examples are provided here:

```
const ligatureMap = {
 "": "ti",
 "": "tf",
  ﬅ: "ft",
 "pla": "platf",
 "AT&amp;T": "AT&T",
}
```

To address this issue, I am attempting to replace the ligatures using the following code:

```
return text.replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]/g, (match) => {
    return ligatureMap[match] || match;
});
```

but it is not converting plaorm to tf and & to &
So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems:

1. Not all of the keys in the `ligatureKeys` object are only one character long, but your regular expression only searches for single character matches (specifically, for single *code unit*¹ matches).
2. At least one of the single-character keys in your object isn't in the range given (`` is char code `\uFB05`).

Separately, there doesn't appear to be an entry in the example `ligaturesMap` for the character in `` in your example. I've assumed it should be `"tt"`.

To make sure all of your `ligatureMap` entries are searched for, including the multi-character ones, you can convert your keys into a regular expression alternation (basically, "this key or that key or this other key"), like this:

```
const rex = new RegExp(
    Object.keys(ligatureMap).map(escapeRegex).join("|"),
    "g"
);
```

The `escapeRegex` function there should be whatever your preferred solution for excaping regular expressions is (perhaps one from [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)).

Here's an example using the `escapeRegex` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/157247) (just as an example):

```js
const text =
    "Verizon is sunseng BlueJeans as the plaorm struggled to gain tracon against rival services in the video conferencing market. Testing: AT&amp;T, 3ﬅ";

const ligatureMap = {
    "": "ti",
    "": "tf",
    "": "tt",
    ﬅ: "ft",
    "pla": "platf",
    "AT&amp;T": "AT&T",
};
const rex = new RegExp(
    Object.keys(ligatureMap).map(escapeRegex).join("|"),
    "g"
);

const updated = text.replace(rex, (match) => {
    return ligatureMap[match] || match;
});

console.log(text);
console.log(updated);


function escapeRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

---

¹ For more about "characters" vs. code points vs code units, see my blog post [*What is a string?*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/)